# Image flickering when Glide loads it

Tags: android, android-glide

I have a list of image views and some of them will be frequently updated with a fixed url. By appending a timestamp query parameter in the end of the url. It works, but I found when it updates it will also clear the current content. Any way to prevent this?

```
// the one needed to update with timestamp appended
image += "?"+String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
Glide.with(mContext.getApplicationContext())
        .load(image)
        .error(R.drawable.default_avatar)
        .centerCrop()
        .crossFade()
        .into(((VideoViewHolder) holder).img);

// the others don't need to update
Glide.with(mContext.getApplicationContext())
        .load(image)
        .error(R.drawable.default_avatar)
        .centerCrop()
        .crossFade()
        .into(((VideoViewHolder) holder).img);
```

Note that the others without timestamp appended are all good.

Comment: So you are saying it flickers instead of crossFade?

Comment: @X3Btel It is crossfade but this isn't what I want. I don't want it to start with placeholder again. I want it to just update to the latest one seamlessly

Comment: Then Id suggest to first load everything like it is not updatable. And then for images that need to be updated call your method, but without crossfade

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
Glide
.with(context)
.load(filepath)
.asBitmap()
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
.skipMemoryCache(true)
.dontAnimate()
.into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {

        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap arg0, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            holder.mItemView.setImageBitmap(arg0);
        }
    });
```

If you're using Glide 3.x and wish to directly display the image without the small crossfade effect, call .dontAnimate() on the Glide request builder:
for more read this : [Glide — Placeholders & Fade Animations](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-placeholders-fade-animations)

Happy coding!!

Comment: Same. Is there any way to update image without clear current content?

Comment: try skipMemoryCache(false). it will keep current data in cache until it has changed.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Emulator, then this can happens.
Try using a real physical device or change the emulator.

Comment: Oh Really? I dont think so

Comment: it's a physical device

Comment: @DayoChoul calling `notifyDataSetChanged`?

Comment: Yes! I face this problem many time. Currently on which project I'm working, I  face a lots of problems like this. Views flickering, Menu flickering, Images flickering and particularly the switches. But after debugging when I install my application on my real device (Truck Emulator Screen), it works great.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya no

Comment: @DayoChoul use `notifyDataSetChanged()` .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya The other fixed ones(no timestamp appended) are all good.